# Run Button Grayed out: Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Why is the run button always grayed out in android studio after I get some errors.
I need to restart/reboot my android studio every time to run it again. I am sure that I am missing something

Run bar: [image]

Run Button: [image]

I also get an error right now :)

```
Already disposed: Project (Disposed): Already disposed: Project (Disposed)
java.lang.AssertionError: Already disposed: Project (Disposed)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiDocumentManager.getInstance(PsiDocumentManager.java:41)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getLastCommittedText(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:521)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.access$400(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:63)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider$DocumentContent.getText(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:537)
    at com.intellij.psi.SingleRootFileViewProvider.getContents(SingleRootFileViewProvider.java:347)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.loadTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:199)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.calcTreeElement(PsiFileImpl.java:776)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.getFirstChild(PsiFileImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.getDocument(XmlFileImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlFileImpl.getRootTag(XmlFileImpl.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LocalResourceRepository.getViewTag(LocalResourceRepository.java:323)
    at org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.IntellijViewTypeDetector.getViewTags(IntellijViewTypeDetector.java:42)
    at com.android.tools.lint.checks.ViewTypeDetector.visitMethod(ViewTypeDetector.java:213)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor$DelegatingJavaVisitor.visitMethodInvocation(JavaVisitor.java:1189)
    at lombok.ast.MethodInvocation.accept(MethodInvocation.java:114)
    at lombok.ast.Cast.accept(Cast.java:94)
    at lombok.ast.BinaryExpression.accept(BinaryExpression.java:131)
    at lombok.ast.ExpressionStatement.accept(ExpressionStatement.java:63)
    at lombok.ast.Block.accept(Block.java:106)
    at lombok.ast.MethodDeclaration.accept(MethodDeclaration.java:240)
    at lombok.ast.NormalTypeBody.accept(NormalTypeBody.java:57)
    at lombok.ast.ClassDeclaration.accept(ClassDeclaration.java:239)
    at lombok.ast.CompilationUnit.accept(CompilationUnit.java:83)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor.visitFile(JavaVisitor.java:217)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkIndividualJavaFiles(LintDriver.java:1652)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:986)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:858)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:425)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:369)
    at org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.AndroidLintExternalAnnotator.doAnnotate(AndroidLintExternalAnnotator.java:146)
    at org.jetbrains.android.inspections.lint.AndroidLintExternalAnnotator.doAnnotate(AndroidLintExternalAnnotator.java:56)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ExternalToolPass.doAnnotate(ExternalToolPass.java:222)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ExternalToolPass.access$400(ExternalToolPass.java:43)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ExternalToolPass$2.run(ExternalToolPass.java:133)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.ExternalToolPass$3.run(ExternalToolPass.java:170)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:298)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$RunnableConsumer.consume(QueueProcessor.java:295)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:110)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:107)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$2.consume(QueueProcessor.java:104)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3$1.run(QueueProcessor.java:215)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor$3.run(QueueProcessor.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you've made major changes to your project structure, it sometimes takes restarting Android Studio to regain the ability to Run your project. Worked for me.

Comment: I have made some major changes and wandering around to enable that run button. At last this answer solved it. But did not require to restart the Android Studio. Just reopened the project. `File > Close Project`

Comment: Just noticed that Close Project is actually much faster than a restart. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yep, every damn time.  Hey JetBrains - lets fix this!

Comment: Amazing that 7 years later this is still not fixed

Comment: Add another - 8 years later this is still not fixed

Comment: 8 and a half years and we are here with a Giraffe but still without a bugfix.

Answer (score 39):

You should initially configure the application.

1. Click the edit configuration in the combo box left to run button then:
   [image]

2. Select the app module

[image]

Comment: My run configuration is ok:
[Run Config](http://i.imgur.com/3mew7CV.png)
It happens when the compiler finds an error. Then I fix the error and the run button stays grayed out.

Comment: Maybe you should just stop the app and then run it again, I mean to stop it in android studio

Comment: Stop is also grayed out :P

Comment: for me my avd was available in the dropdown, so I didn't have to fiddle wit the config screen

Comment: You just save my life and my job I already had a gun pointing at my head right now :/

Comment: @kevingoos Did you ever found out what was the issue? i'm in same boat now with Android Studio 2.3.2

Comment: I am getting in this drop down Menu ``No Module``

Comment: Just add one then

Answer (score 24):

For me, doing a Gradle sync solved that problem :

1. File
2. Sync Project with Gradle Files

Answer (score 7):

After an update of Android Studio or major changes to your project structure,
you need to restart Android Studio and for the first time press run from the dropdown menu

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me when my module settings weren't right. Go to module settings by right clicking the project in the left pane then make sure the target is set to android-23 or whatever version you want

Answer (score 4):

After an update of Android studio the week of writing, the issue got resolved

Comment: also please share the version number of the AS you updated to

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this happened after upgrading the MacOS to Catalina and creating a new user. I had to first reinstall Flutter, get the path and add the path permanently to the environmental variables.

Then I had to go `Preferences` -> `Languages and Frameworks` -> `Flutter` -> add the Flutter SDK (where you installed the latest Flutter) to the Flutter SDK path.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not able to launch android app without activity then perform below mention steps.

1. Open Edit Configuration.
2. Select your application and check the do not launch activity.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this issue by re-importing my Gradle Project. For me, everything was greyed out(Run/Debug/Build), and re-starting Android Studio was not enough to fix this issue.

I did:
`File` -> `Re-Import Gradle Project`.

After a while, all the buttons in the Android Studio IDE started functioning normally again.

Comment: I didn't have this option, the most similar was "File > Invalidate aches / Restart" and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was an issue with the app module which was not selected after Android Studio update. Select the `app` module in the combo box to the left of the run button.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions related to this problem.

Go to <kbd>Setting</kbd>-><kbd>Plugins</kbd>->uncheck the red one's and apply.
Then again mark them (check them ) and apply .

Restart your android studio , it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Just sync the Gradle.

[image]

Done. This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Go to <kbd>Run</kbd> > <kbd>Edit Configuration</kbd> then go to <kbd>Defaults</kbd> > <kbd>Android app</kbd>" then in <kbd>General</kbd> tab select <kbd>App</kbd> in module then "Apply"
This is working for me.

[image: like this]

[image: and like this]

Comment: I am not getting app option under module, it just shows <no module>

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria, if "app" not appear in drop down then follow these steps  "File>Invalidate Caches / Restart...>Invalidate and Restart" and try again above,i hope it will help you

Comment: Yeah I did something similar, I closed project and reopened it, Gradle synced the project and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens without any reason. If there is no problem with `Run configuration`, restarting Android Studio usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the project, and in the screen listing my recent projects, I removed the project and then went to `Open an Existing Android Studio Project` -> `Open`.

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple solution for the one like me for whom nothing mentioned above worked. Just follow:
<kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Clean Project</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Build -> Clean Project and then Build -> Rebuild Project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sync your project. This fixed my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).